# Applying scipy.ndimage.convolve to tridimensional xarray DataArray

Tags: python, scipy, python-xarray

I have a 3D `xarray` DataArray with dimensions x, y, z, and I'm trying to apply [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html) over each x-y plane while maintaining the output as a DataArray. Naturally I'm trying to use `xr.apply_ufunc` to do that. If I do it for only one plane it works perfectly:

```
da=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(5,5,5), dims=("x", "y", "z"))
kernel=np.ones((3,3))
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
conv1 = lambda x: convolve(x, kernel, mode="wrap")
print(xr.apply_ufunc(conv1, da[:,:,0])) # works successfully
```

I'm now trying to come up with a way to do the same for every x-y plane. What I thought was going to work was using `np.apply_along_axis` or `np.apply_over_axes`, but none of them work.

I could iterate over the axis, put everything in a list, and concatenate, but I'm trying to use `xr.apply_ufunc` to avoid problems with the attributes. Is there a way to do that?

Here's an example of something that I thought should work, but that doesn't:

```
np.apply_over_axes(conv1, c, axes=(0,1))
```

but this fails with

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a kernel with shape (3, 3, 1) instead (3, 3)?

```
kernel2d = np.ones((3, 3))
conv2d = lambda x: convolve(x, kernel2d, mode="wrap")
result2d = xr.apply_ufunc(conv2d, da[:, :, 0])

kernel3d = np.ones((3, 3, 1))
conv3d = lambda x: convolve(x, kernel3d, mode="wrap")
result3d = xr.apply_ufunc(conv3d, da)

(result2d == result3d[:, :, 0]).all()  # -> True
```

Another option is to use vectorization logic in `xr.apply_ufunc`, which may be closer to what you tried to do

```
kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
conv = lambda x: convolve(x, kernel, mode="wrap")
result = xr.apply_ufunc(conv, da, input_core_dims=[['x', 'y']], 
                        output_core_dims=[['x', 'y']],
                        vectorize=True)
(result2d == result.transpose('x', 'y', 'z')).all()  # --> True
```

This option is only prepared for convenience and therefore it might be much slower than the first one where the calculation is vectorized.

Comment: I feel very stupid that I didn't think of adding length-1-dimensions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer that I came up with is to manually do this:

```
def conv_rx(da, axis="z"):
    planes = [ xr.apply_ufunc(conv1, da.sel(z=z)) for z in da.z ]
    new = xr.concat(planes, dim=axis)
    return new.transpose(*da.dims)
```

which yields the correct result. However, I'm not very happy with this since it's not elegant and it's pretty slow.